# How to resolve assembly version references conflict easily and what are the best practices

Tags: asp.net, .net, web

I know this has been discussed for individual scenarios, but as a novice to web development I feel it is ok to ask. I started learn web in .Net platform, then I felt that it is a nightmare to resolve conflicts related to assembly references if you are using old applications.

For example when I try to learn through an online course which had sample files, but most of them had old version numbers for assemblies used (eg - Web.Mvc, Web. System.Web.WebPages, System.Web.WebPages.Razor). So I had to go and load the newest assemblies first from Nuget ( I do not know how to load an old version with nuget gui client. maybe have to try in command prompt) and then correct each and every place in .config files (web.config) to use those versions.

I think this is not a good approach when migrating a large application or try to use old applications in a new VS IDE.

I have few questions

1. I would like to know what are the ways of resolving assembly version mismatches?
2. What is the use of public key token specified in references. Although I changed version no I did not change the public key. But they worked. What is the connection between each assembly and public keys?
3. What are the best practices when using such assembly information .config files where we can easily move the application between different machines/servers with different versions(probably a higher version).

Comment: Yes on the web there are tons of examples out there which are old.  This means that in many cases they are no longer valid because in some cases the very methods they use are no longer a part of the current assembly!  However, it doesn't mean the intent of the example is wrong it just means you need to learn how to "use the latest" which is always best and adjust your code accordingly.  But beware, versioning issues are a big deal and they are still very common, many times the result of programming team using poor practices.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Can you tell me about the 'public key' property we use in assembly definitions in files like web.config? Should I care about that key value when changing the version numbers to the latest?

Comment: When an assembly is signed there are two parts, the public and the private key.  In order to use the assembly the user must have the public key.  This is what unlocks the ability to use the assembly.  It also tells you that the assembly you are using is indeed the one you want as no other private key could have been generated to fit the public key you have.